# Where I can get the dump of WHOIS Database?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, network-structure

I am trying to create a neural network based identification network for various websites and with their owners.
I tried to search for database, but could not find any. Kindly, let me know where I can get the complete database dump of whois for websites, so that I can feed that data to my network and process it.

Comment: Potential dublicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/307553/7475279

Comment: I made an FOIA request for it once and was denied. I agree it should be public, but I haven't pursued it legally. Some people claim (probably correctly) that spammers could abuse it.

Comment: @BarryCarter Yes, that might be the right thing. But I am not a spammer. I did apply for the FOIA but same here. I am need of the data for my research and that will help to train the neural structure for prediction.